# analysis of big data

Tags: bigdata

```
# 1.0
#=GF ID   45651
#=GF AC   CD7.8
```

The command i have used is

```
awk '{print $0 > $2 NR}' RS='//' assignment.txt
```

This is generating files with names file0,file1 and so on.

Comment: Are all the strings in the third header unique? Is the file ending with `//` or not? Do you really want your filename to read `#=GF AC PF10487.8.txt` and not `PF10487.8.txt`

Comment: That's a horrible way of naming files on unix/linux environments.  Because of these the trivial uses of tools need to be complicated for everyone else.

Comment: Why did you butcher your question yesterday? It now no longer makes any sense and isn't even a question any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and open file handling:

```
awk -v RS='\n//\n' -F'\n' '{print > ($3 ".txt")}' file
```

That will generate terrible output file names of course since they'll contain both white space and `=` signs and start with `#` but it's what you asked for...

Comment: Should it be needed to close files `awk -v RS='\n//\n' -F'\n' '{o=$3 ".txt"; print > o; close(o)}'` ? Or is this recommended only if we append to file (using `>>`) ?

Comment: No because it requires gawk for multi char RS and gawk internally handles open files for you so you never get the "too many open files" error.

Comment: which tools can I used to split the 100 GB files? Because with Linux , after splitting about 3000, im getting an error. I need to split the 100 GB into 17000 small files with file name ACNo.txt

Comment: The script I posted will work just fine. If you don't tell us what the error is it's unlikely we'll be able to help you debug it.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, considering that you DO NOT want `//` in your output files.

```
awk '
/^\/\//{
  close(file".txt")
  flag=val=""
}
/#=GF AC   PF.*/{
  flag=1
  file=$0
  sub(/^#=/,"",file)
  print val ORS $0 > file".txt"
  next
}
flag{
  print > file".txt"
}
!flag{
  val=val?val ORS $0:$0
}' Input_file
```

Above code will remove `#=` from file names in case you need that too in output file names then remove `sub(/^#=/,"",file)` statement from above code too.

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too now.

```
awk '                               ##awk program starts here.
/^\/\//{                            ##Checking condition if a line has // then do following.
  close(file".txt")                 ##Using close command to close file with file named file".txt" here to avoid TOO MANY FILES OPENED.
  flag=val=""                       ##Nullifying variables flag and val here.
}
/#=GF AC   PF.*/{                   ##Checking condition if a line starts from #=GF AC   PF .* will match anything here, if yes then do following.
  flag=1                            ##Setting variable flag as 1 here.
  file=$0                           ##Setting variable file value to current line here.
  sub(/^#=/,"",file)                ##Substituting #= from start of the line with variable file.
  print val ORS $0 > file".txt"     ##Printing variable val ORS(output record separator) current line and printing it to file".txt"
  next                              ##next will skip all further statements from here onward.
}
flag{                               ##Checking condition if variable flag is SET then do following.
  print > file".txt"                ##Printing current lines to file".txt" file name.
}
!flag{                              ##Checking condition here is variable flag is NOT SET then do following.
  val=val?val ORS $0:$0             ##Creating variable val and concatenating to its own value.
}' Input_file                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```